# Вирутальные и не очень машины и сети|часть 2

Tags: dhcp, virtualbox

Доброго времени суток.В продолжении своей темы [http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/3173/вирутальные-и-не-очень-машины-и-сетиРассмотрим](http://admin.hashcode.ru/questions/3173/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC) простейший случай.Есть виртуальный хост-роутер.Имеет DHCP-сервер раздающий адреса.В нем три сетевых карты которые должны соответствовать трем локальным сетям.Так же есть виртуальных хоста как "представители" этих сетей.Адреса они тоже должны получать по DHCP.Итого,что нужно...![alt text][1]Как бы заставить маншину "Alpha" конектиться к сетевой карте eth1?"Beta"->eth2 "Gamma"->eth3.Желательно не используя статическую привязку к МАКам этих машин.Иначе говоря-как сделать чтоб машина присоединялась к той сети которой ей запланировано.А то ситуация грустная и все машины лезут в сеть организуемую через eth3  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQnFQ.jpg

Comment: Получается у вас каким-то образом смешано три широковещательных домена? В реальной сети так ведь не делается. У вас каждая из машин будет "висеть" на своем интерфейсе, в своей сети. Можно, хотя не уверен, попробовать поместить каждый хост в отдельную рабочую группу и связать ДХЦП с каждой из них.

Comment: вот имеено я бы так и хотел "поместить каждый хост в отдельную рабочую группу и связать ДХЦП с каждой из них" но нет идей за что зацепиться.Пока только привяка к макаадресу и выдача ип по нему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А собственно зачем Вам столько сетевух, я бы на дхцп машине поднял бы vlan, тегом отдавал каждому из участков сети по vlan tag.Например ALPHA - 192.168.0.0/24 - vlan 5BETA - 192.168.1.0/24 - vlan 10, etc... На хост машинах естественно тоже vlan'ы, или коммутатор с поддержкой vlan

Answer (score 0):

Возможно так и сделаю.Просто раньше знаний о приницпах и устройствах vlan-не было.Спасибо за мысль.